# Run webpage or local page from Extension by Application Mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have read this article on stackoverflow:

**You can run Chrome in application mode.**

> **Windows**:
>
> Chrome.exe --app=https://google.com
>
> **Mac**:
>
> /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
>   --app=https://google.com
>
> **Linux**:
>
> google-chrome --app=https://google.com This removes all toolbars, not
>   just the address bar, but it will definitely increase your real estate
>   without having to use Kiosk mode.

I want to call this task from my Chrome extension. I mean from my extension, if use click on button "load in app mode" then it will run above command. How can I call?

Something I need look like that:

```
chrome.extension.runapp("Chrome.exe --app=https://google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

An application is still self-contained. A Chrome app can't tell your computer to run other processes, including other Chrome processes. If your user wants to open something as an app, they still have to do that themselves.